# Несмотря на настройку, Docker продолжает выдавать рандомный IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Нагуглил такой подход к конфигурированию статичного IP:

```
version: '3'
    
networks:
  app-network:
    external:
      name: my_network

app:
image: php:7.1-fpm
networks:
  app-network:
    ipv4_address: 172.15.1.5
```

Сеть создана такой командой:

```
docker network create --gateway 172.15.1.1 --subnet 172.15.1.0/24 my_network
```

Docker всё равно продолжает выдавать рандомный IP, а нужен статичный. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совершенно внезапно, спустя около часа гугления, в голову пришло озарение, что я не в ту секцию ломлюсь, у меня же контент отдаёт другой сервис! На всякий случай решил не удалять тред, так как возможно кому-то сэкономит время в будущем! Ну и сам вопрос по сути гайд как сделать это на docker-compose v3, пришлось по кусочкам собирать.

```
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.17
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.15.1.5
```